# Save a texture to a file in Android & OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, framebuffer

As far as I understand sending a texture to OGLES2 is done using `GLUtils.texImage2D`, i.e. I upload the texture to the GPU. How do I send it back to Android then (download it from the GPU)?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Obviously using `glReadPixels`, e.g.:

```
GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, mFboWidth, mFboHeight, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mPixels);
```

Comment: And how are you getting mPixels?